# Trying to install Ubuntu on i686 cpu

Tags: boot, system-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu, but received an error message that I can not install as my computer has an i686 CPU.

Do I need a different version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Were you trying to install Ubuntu 64-bit (amd64)?

Looks like you have a 32-bit processor so try installing Ubuntu 32-bit version(i386)